# Scroll displays itself for no reason in Phonegap app

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm building an application using Phonegap build. The app is just another list app with an input field and an "insert" button. The user after typing the phrase he wants to save and presses the button to insert the value, the value is shown inside a scroll box. Here is the code (HTML, jQuery, CSS) for the scroll box:

```
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        center();
   });

        function center(){
        var wh = $(window).height()*0.56;
        $('#demo').css({'height':wh+'px'});
        }
</script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div id="demo" align="center" class="col-md-12"></div>

</div>
</div>

<style>
#demo {
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-left: 30px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

The #demo is the place where the scrollbox is. My problem is this:
[image]

The scrollbar displays itself even when I open the app for the first time. I tried it on many phones and the half of them have this issue and in the others the scrollbar doesn't appear. I searched the web but I couldn't find a similar problem. Do you know how I can make the scrollbar become invisible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried to set `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: auto;`? if not try to use it like this

```
<style>
#demo {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-left: 30px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Technically, this is a question, not an answer.